# Opening files in new window instead of downloading them

Tags: php, html

I have the option for viewing or downloading files on a site.

For PDF's it works fine, I expect it will with images too but there are other document types that I'm using such as Keynote, Word, Pages, Excel, etc etc.  When I select to view these they open a blank window and are downloaded instead.

Is there a way around this at all?

```
<div class="viewAndDownload">
<p><strong>Views: </strong><?php echo $views ?><span>&nbsp;</span> <a href="<?php echo $viewFile ?>" target="_blank"><img src="../images/book_next.png" alt="view file" border="0"/></a></a></p>

</div>
<div class="viewAndDownload">
<p><strong>Downloads:</strong> <?php echo $downloads ?> <span>&nbsp; &nbsp;</span><a href="../download.php?filename=<?php echo $fileName?>"><img src="../images/disk.png" alt="view file" border="0"/></a></p>

</div>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Simple answer is you can't.  Word is required to read the document and display properly.  There may be some plugin out there that will work that I'm not aware of for the server.  There are browser plugins but that is client side dependent.  Which puts this question off topic.

Comment: Which specific filetypes are you looking for? There might be a viewer you can find for those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of finding a viewer or browser add-on this is not possible. I would certainly not recommend it with Excel due to the possibility malware through macros. It is possible with PDF's because Adobe Reader acts as a viewer and add on for most browsers. It is also possible with Video files like .mp4 or Wmv(I.e 8+) because these browsers have add-ons or players built in for these files. Sadly, for using things like Excel and word these do not exist. The only work around I can think of, is loading the data from the file for example CSV from Excel. I have created a generic excel reader like that before.

Comment: Cheers Robert, that's at least removed the idea and stopped me wasting a lot of hours hunting around on google :)